# django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (academic_grade) specified for User

Tags: python, django

I am creating a form, inside forms.py I have:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name',
                  'username', 'email', 'academic_grade',]
```

But I get the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (academic_grade) specified for User
```

I check in the database and user table have the 'academic_grade' grade column

models.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, default='')
    academic_grade = models.CharField(choices=GRADE_CHOICES, default='')
```

please guide me through this

Comment: I have more code inside models.py but I only put that line.. if you need to see the entire class let me know pls.

Comment: Are you sure you are importing your `User` model in the forms and not the `django.contrib.auth.models.User`?

Comment: Are you using the user model from `django.contrib.auth` or did you import your models User and did you migrate?

Comment: Did you remember to set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in your settings.

Comment: omg, Thanks for the commends, the problem was that pycharm help me to import User class but did not import the correct User model. lol. Thanks. How do I give you points ??

Comment: I solved the same issue by import my `User` as `from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model` then `User = get_user_model()`

Comment: The same error I was facing and observed that if field name in model and field name in Forms list (inside meta) is different then you will face a similar issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you run  -

```
  python manage.py migrate
```

django will migrate all inbuilt models present in the following apps-

```
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes'
```

From  **django.contrib.auth** app , there is a inbuilt table User , that have the following fields -

```
 Column    |

 id
 password
 last_login
 is_superuser
 username
 first_name
 last_name
 email
 is_staff
 is_active
 date_joined
```

I am afraid , this is being picked by the django (either by wrongly import or by running migration command before actually creating your own User).
The latter one will actually create User before your models.

Therefore , I would suggest you to either cross check your import or try giving some other name to your user.For e.g

```
   class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
      password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

      class Meta:
         model = Person
         fields = ['first_name', 'last_name',
              'username', 'email', 'academic_grade',]
```

Let me know, if it helps or correct me if you think so !

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One more possible scenario is you might forget to add `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in your setting. (It happens to me many times).

I will suggest you not to use User as class name if you build a customUser class.

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, default='')
    academic_grade = models.CharField(choices=GRADE_CHOICES, default='')
```

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name',
                  'username', 'email', 'academic_grade',]
```

and in setting.py add

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'appName.CustomUser'
```

In case you forget to add `AUTH_USER_MODEL`, when you migrate, the default django auth field are created. You can verify those in the migration file. As such any custom fields you try to call in form.py will nor be available.