# django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field specified for CustomUser

Tags: python, django

I just want to add one field (organization) to the auth_user model of my Django 2.2 app.

settings.py:

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        ...
        'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
        ...
    ]
    ...
    AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.CustomUser'
```

accounts\models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    organization = 'organization'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

accounts\forms.py

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

class Meta:
    model = django_apps.get_model(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, require_ready=False)
    fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'organization', 'password1', 'password2')

def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    self.fields['username'].label = 'Username'
    self.fields['email'].label = 'Email Address'
    self.fields['first_name'].label = 'First Name'
    self.fields['last_name'].label = 'Last Name'
    self.fields['organization'].label = 'Organization'
```

accounts\apps.py

```
class AccountsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'accounts'
```

admin.py

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
form = CustomUserChangeForm
model = CustomUser
list_display = ['email', 'username',]
...
admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

This is the Traceback:

```
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
  (..library stuff...)
  File "X\staticsheet\accounts\admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomUserChangeForm
  File "X\staticsheet\accounts\forms.py", line 21, in <module>
    class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
  File "X\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 266, in __new__
    raise FieldError(message)
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (organization) specified for CustomUser
```

I've been looking for a solution to this everywhere and I've been following a simple tutorial but I keep getting this error. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44529728/django-core-exceptions-fielderror-unknown-fields-academic-grade-specified-f

Comment: In your models.py specify `models.CharField()` for `organization`

Comment: FBSO I looked at that question before and I think it might've been the field type Subham. I also found that one of the views was referencing the original User model directly and things seem to be working after I removed that. Thanks for your help. Now I have to figure out this 'relation "django_site_domain_a2e37b91_uniq" already exists' error when I try to migrate.